# How to request JSON Data from a web API using AsyncHttpClient and base 64 encoded string?

Tags: java, android, json, http

```
public static String[] makeRequest(String uri, String base64encodedImage) throws IOException {

        final JSONObject[] json = {new JSONObject()};

        String data ="";
        final String[] result = new String[1];
        //URL _url = new URL(uri);

        final AsyncHttpClient[] httpClient = {new AsyncHttpClient()};
        httpClient[0].addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpClient[0].setUserAgent("GYUserAgentAndroid");
        String jsonParamsString = "{\"key\":\"value\"}";
        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams("request", jsonParamsString);
        httpClient[0].put(uri, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                        super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                        result[0] = response.toString();
                        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        //toast.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                        super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                        result[0] = "failed";
                    }
                }
        );

        try {
            json[0].put( "imageData", base64encodedImage);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //json.put( "caption", );

        return result;
```

I am trying to get JSON data from an API called Calorie Mama (https://dev.caloriemama.ai/docs) using an android device. I have to send an image to the API and I have already converted the image into a base 64 encoded string. However, I am not getting any data back from the API. This is the class that should receive the data but it is not working. It would be great if you could tell me why. I am new to android development. :(

The activity below instantiates the makeRequest class.

```
package com.example.takeimage;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Evaluate extends AppCompatActivity {
    String base64encodedImage;
    String baseURI = "https://api-2445582032290.production.gw.apicast.io/v1/foodrecognition?user_key=[my Api Key]";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_evaluate);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(message);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        base64encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        makeRequest newRequest = new makeRequest();
        String[] result= null;
        try {
            result = newRequest.makeRequest(baseURI, base64encodedImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), result[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        //TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textEvaluate);
        //txtView.setText(base64encodedImage);
    }
    protected void response(){
        final String url = baseURI + "/postformdata";
    }


}
```